# Arquivo de configuração para formulários

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Existe alguma maneira de criar um arquivo onde eu posso definir por exemplo, uma cor com o nome 'Fundo' e adicionar o valor '#fff', depois usar ela em todos os meus forms, semelhante a um style do CSS, para que caso eu precise mudar essa cor eu não precise trocar em todos os forms um a um?

Eu vi algo sobre Singleton, mas não sei se seria o ideal para o que eu preciso, que é apenas informar uma cor ou texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como Maniero falou, no `Windows Forms`, você utiliza a herança. Um Singleton, ou criar "um arquivo onde eu posso definir ... uma cor com o nome 'Fundo' e adicionar o valor '#fff'" pode até funcionar, mas será gambiarra. Imagine só em todo construtor de `Form` você ter que ir lá e colocar: `this.BackColor = minhaClasseStylesSingleton.Fundo;`

Essa utilização seria viável, mas para pontos específicos, por exemplo, definir mensagens, ou cores de certos objetos.

Voltando à herança do WinForms, é bem simples (Basta não querer resolver tudo em um único formulário):

Você cria um Form com as características que serão aplicadas a todos os forms do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(não foi alterado nada no código do Form)

Agora, nos próximos Forms, basta você trocar a herança:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class FormFilho : FormBase
    {
        public FormFilho()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Pronto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que as propriedades são carregadas com o valor padrão do Form Pai (FormBase).

> Observações:

Você ainda pode alterar esses propriedades no Form filho e elas serão aplicadas apenas nele.

Você pode ter um terceiro Form, que herde o FormFilho e assim sucessivamente.

Cuidado ao querer resolver tudo em um Form só, adicionar um controle no Forms pai por exemplo, ele estará disponível em todos os Forms filhos e não será possível removê-lo. Removê-lo do `Form` pai, trará problemas aos Forms filhos.

Para acessar os controles de Forms superiores nos Forms Filhos, basta você alterar a propriedade `Modifiers` para [o valor desejado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

Answer (score 4):

Talvez, tem duas formas de pensar isso. pelo que está dizendo, sim, tem.

Chama-se orientação a objetos. Algo que as pessoas dizem que fazem, mas desconhecem totalmente o que seja, como se aplica.

O mecanismo exclusivo da orientação a objetos é a herança, algo que praticamente nunca vi alguém fazer no Windows Forms e é onde OOP melhor se aplica.

Você cria um controle com certas características e sempre que precisa de um controle semelhante que mantenha as mesmas características você herda deste controle, assim todos os herdados recebem estas características. O que provavelmente já sabe é que este controle pode, e provavelmente deve herdar de um controle já existente. E pode ser que este novo controle pode ser abstrato, só para organizar. Pode deixar as classes descendentes modificar o valor ou não, o que pode ser um pouco diferente do que quer.

Se quiser que a mudança ocorra de forma dinâmica, e o CSS não trabalha assim, onde pode mudar na hora e seja transferi automaticamente para os descendentes, aí precisa de um mecanismo que faça isto, provavelmente com eventos onde as descendentes assinam eventos da ascendente, talvez até automaticamente.

Por outro lado pode estar falando não de formulários e sim de controles que são aninhados uns dentro dos outros. Isto não tem nada pronto e geralmente faz pouco sentido no WinForms e provavelmente em outros formas, salvo algo muito restrito e específico. Neste caso os controles que são filhos de outros, ou seja, são vinculados dentro do controle já existente, algo como colocar um *label* ou um *textbox* dentro de um *form*. As propriedades de um form costumam ser diferentes. Mesmo as que são iguais tem motivações diferenças, não faz muito sentido querer que a cor de fundo do formulário seja automaticamente replicada no *textbox*. O que pode fazer é estabelecer cor transparente por exemplo em um *label* e isso significa que a cor de fundo será a mesma do formulário porque não é pra ter um cor, não é branco, ou preto, é sem cor, isso é feito.

Não consigo imaginar onde Singleton entra nisso, alias me parece ser o oposto do que precisa. A não ser que a pergunta seja sobre outra coisa completamente diferente.

A pergunta é bem geral e a resposta foi na mesma linha.